# GETPIVOTDATA formula for PowerPivot Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm trying to make an automated dashboard using multiple PowerPivot Tables and trying to automate it. I have the current formula to extract the number based on a date below. The intention is to enter the date in `cell B3` that has the date 3/5/21.
How can I reference the formula to include the date value in cell `B3` instead of the below `"[Range].[Week Ending in].&[**2021-03-05T00:00:00**]")"`?

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Count of TASK 2]",$A$41,"[Range].[Sprint Ending in]","[Range].[Sprint Ending in].&[Sprint 1]","[Range].[Week Ending in]","[Range].[Week Ending in].&[2021-03-05T00:00:00]")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the table well, you could change your last argument to:

```
"[Range].[Week Ending in].["&B3&"]"
```

so that the function would be:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Count of TASK 2]",$A$41,"[Range].[Sprint Ending in]","[Range].[Sprint Ending in].&[Sprint 1]","[Range].[Week Ending in]","[Range].[Week Ending in].["&B3&"]")
```

This assumes that B3 contains "2021-03-05T00:00:00". If it only contains "5/3/21", then you need to use this as the argument:

```
"[Range].[Week Ending in].["&TEXT(B3,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"T00:00:00"&"]"
```

which would make the function look like this:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Count of TASK 2]",$A$41,"[Range].[Sprint Ending in]","[Range].[Sprint Ending in].&[Sprint 1]","[Range].[Week Ending in]","[Range].[Week Ending in].["&TEXT(B3,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"T00:00:00"&"]")
```